# Can I use my Girocard V-Pay for money withdrawal in every EU country?

Tags: europe, payment-cards, eu, atms

I have the Girocard V-Pay card issued by Postbank. According to [Wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_Pay), this card can be used in ATMs within European Union, that would suggest, in each EU-country.

However, I'm a bit skeptical and I don't want risking being without money abroad. How does it look in praxis? Is this card really accepted in every ATM in EU, or it is accepted only in some ATMs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important thing to do, is to know what flag your card belongs. What I realized in my trips was the ATM don't cares about the bank or country of your card. The flag is important. If the flag belongs to Visa or Mastercard, being assured that even most of ATMs will accept this.

This is important also to discover if the bank that has emitted your card has agreement with other banks around the world. This implies on: if you can't withdraw your money on any from an ATM, you can do it on a bank that has agreement with yours.

But don't carry all your money in your card. For you own safe, it's important to carry some amount in cash. That prevent you both in case of lost of your card and in case of you can't withdraw your money in an ATM machine.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: VPay is some type of Visa which should answer the flag question.